# Passing $_FILES as variable, returns both result and error.

Tags: php, file-upload, superglobals

Trying to execute file upload through external function. It gives "Missing argument..." error but also returns the result correctly. What might be wrong?

This is form page:

```
<?php include '--formprocess.php'; ?>
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $upload = $_FILES['upload'];
        if(formprocess($upload)) {
        echo formprocess();
    } else {
        echo 'ERROR!';
    }
}
?>
```

and process file:

```
<?php
function formprocess($upload) {
    $name = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
    return $name;
}
```

Comment: `function formprocess($upload)` there is clearly an argument required there. `echo formprocess();` <~ no argument passed. You're also using a function that returns a string, in an if block?

Comment: looks like you should be just passing $_FILES to the function as well seeing as the function references the upload key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    echo formprocess();
                     ^---your missing argument
```

Answer (score 0):

`formprocess` takes one argument, the first time you call it you passed an argument, the second time you did not.

```
$value = formprocess($upload);
if($value) {
    echo $value;
}
```